I want to show the comment immediately on the screen with comments list
when I post comment I have to fetch the comment list (all product details) again to show the new comment
I use combine , any solution to show the comment immediately in the comments list when post?
class ProductDetailsViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var productDetails: ProductDetails? = nil
    @Published  var commentText: String = ""
    func fetchProductDetails(id: Int){
        isLoading = true
        service.fetchProductDetails(id: id)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] completion in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.isLoading = false
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
                self?.productDetails = response.data
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    } 

func postComment(id: Int){
        isLoading = true
        let parameters: [String: Any] = ["comment": commentText]
        service.postRequest(url: Config.baseURL+"item/\(id)/comment", parameters: parameters, type: CommentResponse.self)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] completion in
                self?.isLoading = false
                switch completion{
                case .finished:
                    break
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
                if let message = response.message{
                    self?.message = message
                }
                self?.commentText = ""
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)

  if let comments = product.comments, !comments.isEmpty {
                 VStack(spacing: 10){
                    ForEach(comments, id: \.id){ comment in
                        AdCommentCellView(comment: comment)
                    }
                }


After posting, immediately make a GET or fetch request to the API and display the comments. Show a loader to allow users to wait and see their comments.

To make the new comment appear immediately after posting, you don't need to fetch the entire product details again. You can modify the comments list directly after successfully posting a new comment and update the @Published property to trigger the UI update.
class ProductDetailsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var productDetails: ProductDetails? = nil
    @Published var commentText: String = ""
    @Published var message: String = ""
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    // Fetch Product Details
    func fetchProductDetails(id: Int) {
        isLoading = true
        service.fetchProductDetails(id: id)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] completion in
                self?.isLoading = false
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    // Handle error here
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
                self?.productDetails = response.data
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    // Post Comment and Update Comments List
    func postComment(id: Int) {
        isLoading = true
        let parameters: [String: Any] = ["comment": commentText]
        service.postRequest(url: Config.baseURL + "item/\(id)/comment", parameters: parameters, type: CommentResponse.self)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] completion in
                self?.isLoading = false
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    // Handle error here
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                if let message = response.message {
                    self.message = message
                }

                // Create a new comment object
                let newComment = Comment(id: UUID().uuidString, text: self.commentText)
                
                // Append the new comment to the product's comments list
                self.productDetails?.comments.append(newComment)

                // Clear the comment text after posting
                self.commentText = ""
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
`

